# Conditional probability of a Royal flush

Tags: probability, combinatorics

What is the probability of drawing a 10, jack, queen, king, and ace of all the same suit from 5 random cards given that one card drawn is an ace of spades?

**Solution**
Let $R$ denote the event that the hand is a royal flush and let $S_A$ be the event that one card is ace of spades.

Clearly, $$P(R) = \frac{4}{{52}\choose{5}}.$$

Now we intuition we see that 
$$P(R|S_A) = {{51}\choose{4}}^{-1},$$
because there are only 51 cards left after $S_A$.

Now let us compute this conditional probability using the usual definition. The textbook (Stirzaker, Elementary Prob., 2nd ed, p. 53)  correctly says:

$$P(R|S_A) = \frac{P(R\cap S_A)}{P(S_A)}=\frac{{{52}\choose{5}}^{-1}}{{{51}\choose{4}}\big/{{52}\choose{5}}}.$$

Now, while I see that $P(R\cap S_A) = {{52}\choose{5}}^{-1}$ I would say that $P(S_A)  = 1/52 \neq {{51}\choose{4}}\big/{{52}\choose{5}},$ because there is only one ace of spades in a standard deck of 52 cards. But this does not give the correct conditional probability of $R$ given $S_A$. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your $1/52$ is effectively the probability that the first card is ace of spades.

Consider $P(S_A)$ when drawing the cards one by one where the order matters. Since we are considering the probability and not the number of permutations, this will be equivalent to the "draw $5$ cards at once" where the order doesn't matter.

The probability that the first card is ace of spades is $\frac1{52}$. Then the following cards don't matter so $\frac1{52} \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 = \frac1{52}$.

The probability that the second card is ace of spades is $\frac{51}{52} \cdot \frac{1}{51}$ and then the following cards don't matter so $\frac{51}{52} \cdot \frac1{51} \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 = \frac1{52}$ .

Similarly, the probability that the third card is ace of spades is  $\frac{51}{52} \cdot \frac{50}{51} \cdot \frac1{50} \cdot 1 \cdot 1 = \frac1{52}$.

The probability that aces of spades appears on the 4th and 5th draw are also $\frac1{52}$.

The five situations listed above are disjoint, thus $\frac1{52} + \frac1{52} +\frac1{52} +\frac1{52} +\frac1{52} = \frac5{52}$, which is also ${{51}\choose{4}}\big/{{52}\choose{5}}$.

When one wants to take the approach of "draw $5$ cards at once" where the order doesn't matter, the denominator must be ${{52}\choose{5}}$ and the numerator shall be the number of combinations of whatever event is requested. One cannot directly obtain $\frac1{52}$ under this approach.

Comment: Ok I got it. I was misinterpreting the $S_A$ as "drawing ace of spades in a single card draw" instead of "in a five card draw, one is ace of spades and the others are any". In the former $P(S_A) = 1/52$ but in the latter it is $5/52$.

Comment: Glad I could help. If your questions are mostly resolved, then you might consider clicking on the green check mark and "accept", this will wrap up the post and avoid it staying in the wrong queue clogging up the system. Thank you.